# how I can fix android background image

Tags: android, css

[image]

Hi. I have android app but don't can fix the image briefly at the sides.

activity style

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="96dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        style="@style/FacebookLoginButton"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

please help, how I can fix it

Comment: You don't have image crop using "background" img value... sadly. Look for an alternative. Use a ImageView so the crop center looks great for every screen. (you can do some others bitmaps process to achieve that but not sure is worth the spending time).

Answer (score 0):

To support multiple screen resolutions on android, You should add the background images of particular resolution in your drawable folder.

You can follow these image dimensions

xxxhdpi: 1280x1920 px

xxhdpi: 960x1600 px

xhdpi: 640x960 px

hdpi: 480x800 px

mdpi: 320x480 px

ldpi: 240x320 px

Specific to your case, for your Custom Tablet: If you create an image of dimension 2560x1600 and put it in drawable folder, it will perfectly fit in your tablet screen

Here is link to get more information on same
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html